# I want to pass value from my Angular4 App to installed node_module

Tags: angular, npm

I have an angular4 app in which I have installed an NPM module from my Pvt Registry. How can I pass a string value from my main app (where the module is installed) to the NPM module?

Comment: What do you mean by passing Value from AGS4 to node_module?

Comment: I have an Angular4 app which is my main app in which I install a node_module from my PVT NPM registry. 
Now, I want to pass API URL from my main app to the installed node_module
I don't want the API URL to be hardcoded while publishing the module instead it should be configurable.
Like whichever app installs the node_module can pass the API URL.